# How can i send latitude and longitude every 15 minute to php web service?

Tags: android

I am new to android. I want to send latitude and longitude every 15 minute to web service .Ho can i do this? How can i use Alarm Manager to send data every 15 minute?

Comment: why are you asking a same question so many times?

Answer (score 0):

1. Start a service or thread from  your activity.
2. put a timer for every 15 minutes.
3. at every 15 minutes just call the onLocationChanged() for location update and 
   save it then pass the value to your activity and use it.

Comment: onLocationChanged() is a callback method you can't call it by yourself